# Will the server gets overloaded if millions of request are generated for the page which doesn't exists?

Tags: php, httpwebrequest

Will the server gets overloaded if millions of request are sent for the page which doesn't exists?

How to block such requests?

Comment: And also "How long is a piece of string"

Comment: If those millions of requests are over a ten year period, then it probably won't swamp any server; if you're talking about millions of requests per second, then it's probably going to be overloaded... where are these millions of requests coming from?

Comment: Thanks Mark, How Can I get rid of such request so that server will not get overloaded.